# Word Merge with Excel Datasource

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single page Word doc.  I have an Excel sheet with multiple rows of names, addresses, etc.   I'm trying to get each row to merge into the Word document line by line and NOT create a new document.  I've tried inserting the Rule for Next Record and Next Record If.  Nothing is working.  It will either merge the first row and then create a second document with the second row's info and so forth OR it will create the first document with the first row and then STOP.   Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here's what I've done:

```
«Attorney_First_Name» «Attorney_Initial» «Attorney_Last_Name», «Title»
«M_2nd_Atty_FN» «M_2nd_Atty_Initial» «M_2nd_Atty_LN», «M_2nd_Title»
«FIRM_NAME»
«Street_Address»
«City_State_Zip»
«Email_Attorneys»
ATTORNEYS FOR «PARTY_NAME»
{NEXTIF {MERGEFIELD Attorney_First_Name }<>"" }
```

Comment: If you are using Mail Merge and Step-by-step Mail Merge Wizard, in the last step, you can click Finish & Merge > Edit Individual Documents to merge to a new document. These record will be included in a new document.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and it merges each record into a separate document.   I need all the names in one single document.   Any other thoughts?